Few shot prompting with HuggingFace serverless endpoint and Langchain
I create access to justice software for not for profits. Currently, I am trying to build a tool that extracts specific information from unstructured data. This information being the reference to human rights articles that were violated or not.
I have succesffully built this tool utilising, HF Serverless Endpoint and Langchain with a tool calling function.
I am now attempting to include few shot prompting to improve the quality of the output. However, I receive this error code:

Failed to process case id 3241: 'Input to ChatPromptTemplate is missing variables {'\n      "violated_articles"'}.  Expected: ['\n      "violated_articles"', 'query'] Received: ['query']'

I receive the above error code for my code which follows. However, I believe the issue may lie with how the examples variable is formatted to include a json file. The documentation provides simple integers as arguments:
class Json(BaseModel):
    violated_articles: list[str]
    non_violated_articles: list[str]
    success: bool

tools = [Json]

llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
    repo_id="meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-70B-Instruct",
    task="text-generation",
    max_new_tokens=512,
    do_sample=False,
    temperature=0.01,
    seed = 1997,
)

system_message_content = """
    You are tasked with identifying the human rights articles and their subsection that were violated or not.

    Adhere strictly to the following rules when providing the response:
    1. Base your response solely on the user content.
    2. List only the article numbers with their subsection if it exists without additional text or explanation.
    3. If there is difficulty in extracting or no mention of articles, state success as 'false'
    4. Do not repeat any article
    5. Provide the output in the following JSON format only:
    {
      "violated_articles": [comma-separated list of violated article numbers],
      "non_violated_articles": [comma-separated list of non-violated article numbers],
      "success": [true/false]
    }
    """

examples = [
    HumanMessage(
        """"
        1.  Decides, unanimously, to join the applications;
        2.  Holds, by five votes to two, that there would be no violation of Article 3, Article 2-1 §§ 5  in conjunction with 1 of Protocol No. 1 of the Convention in the event of the applicants’ extradition to Kyrgyzstan;
        3.  Decides, by six votes to one, to continue to indicate to the Government under Rule 39 of the Rules of Court that it is desirable, in the interests of the proper conduct of the proceedings, not to extradite.
        4.  Holds, by fifteen votes to two, that there is a violation of Article 6 § 1, 9(6) taken in conjunction with 14, and P1-2  of the Convention.
        """,
        name="example_user"
    ),
    AIMessage(
        "",
        name="example_assistant",
        tool_calls=[
            {"name": "Json", "args": {"violated_articles": ["6-1","9-6","14","P1-2"], "non_violated_articles": ["3", "2-1", "5", "P1-1"], "success": True}, "id": "1"}
        ],
    ),
    ToolMessage(json.dumps({"violated_articles": ["6-1","9-6","14","P1-2"], "non_violated_articles": ["3", "2-1", "5", "P1-1"], "success": True}), tool_call_id="1"),
    AIMessage(
        json.dumps({"violated_articles": ["6-1","9-6","14","P1-2"], "non_violated_articles": ["3", "2-1", "5", "P1-1"], "success": True}),
        name="example_assistant",
    ),
]


conn, cursor = connect_psql()
ids = retrieve_unprocessed_ids(cursor)
chat_model = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm)
llm_with_json = chat_model.bind_tools(tools, tool_choice="Json")

for id_tuple in ids[:1]:
    id = id_tuple[0]
    print(id)
    conclusion = retrieve_conclusion(cursor, id)
    if conclusion:
        user_prompt = conclusion[0]
        user_prompt = """
    Holds, by five votes to two, that there would be no violation of Article 3 of the Convention in the event of the applicants’ extradition to Kyrgyzstan;
        """

        try:
            response = None
            # Create the messages list
            few_shot_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
                [
                    ("system", system_message_content),
                    *examples,
                    ("human", "{query}"),
                ]
            )
            chain = {"query": RunnablePassthrough()} | few_shot_prompt | llm_with_json
            response = chain.invoke(user_prompt)

Ī have tried to change the arguments to a string, to match what the arguments are for the code that runs without any examples. The output for that code is:

content='' additional_kwargs={'tool_calls': [ChatCompletionOutputToolCall(function=ChatCompletionOutputFunctionDefinition(arguments={'non_violated_articles': ['Article 3'], 'success': True, 'violated_articles': []}, name='Json', description=None), id='0', type='function')]} response_metadata={'token_usage': ChatCompletionOutputUsage(completion_tokens=50, prompt_tokens=199, total_tokens=249), 'model': '', 'finish_reason': 'eos_token'} id='run-2ed7c88a-ec65-4b31-8025-9013f3b7da9b-0' invalid_tool_calls=[{'name': 'Json', 'args': '{"non_violated_articles": ["Article 3"], "success": True, "violated_articles": []}', 'id': '0', 'error': None}]


I fixed this issue through ensuring that the tool call was a valid response, not invalid, which meant simplifying the Pydantic model.
Now I am facing an issue where the output of the llm is including some references to the examples
